# AndroidStudio order mixed up when using Intents to open Activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

In my app I have 3 activities:
LoginPage
RegisterActivity
TeacherRegistration

I have a button in LoginPage activity that when I press it , the RegisterActvity is open and I implement this by creating Intent and start it when the button is presses.
So far so good, the problem started when I added another button in my RegisterActivity and wanted to have another Intent that when I click the button in my RegisterActivity it will open the TeacherRegistration activity but what happened is that now when I click on my first button (meaning the button in LoginPage activity) it's directly open the TeacherRegistration activity (skipping the RegisterActivity).
Here is some of the code:

LoginPage Activity:

```
public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

    onRegisterBtnListener();
}

public void onRegisterBtnListener() {
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.noamm_000.tincherfirsttry.RegisterActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

RegisterActivity Activity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button continueRegister;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    onContinueRegisterBtnListener();
}
public void onContinueRegisterBtnListener() {
    continueRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_continueRegister);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.noamm_000.tincherfirsttry.TeacherRegistration");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

and the AndroidMainifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.noamm_000.tincherfirsttry.RegisterActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TeacherRegistration">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.noamm_000.tincherfirsttry.TeacherRegistration" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you,

Noam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set  OnClickListener of `continueRegister` the same way as you do it in the first activity. Currently you effectively start intent immediately in onCreate().
Kind of

```
public void onContinueRegisterBtnListener() {
    continueRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_continueRegister);
    continueRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.noamm_000.tincherfirsttry.TeacherRegistration");
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: ohhh you right.. missed that.. I'm an idiot. thank you @Serg